# Add Image to HTML string dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add image src from array. I am able to add it as hardcoded. Below is my code.

```
var newDiv = "<li>"+names[i]+"<br><br><center><img src = a.png></img>    </center><br>"+subnames[i]+"</li>";
```

In above code A.PNG is hardcoded. Please tell me how to add it from array images();

Comment: `a.png` should be in double quotes (`"`) and you're already doing string concatenation with `names[i]` so why can't you just do it again?

Comment: I am doing it. But its displaying name of the image instaed of actual image

Comment: Not in double quotes. Use single quote and it should show your image. If you want to show it from array images just use src = "+images[i]+" .. Learn basics of js

Answer (score 1):

just do the same like what you already did, for the `image` like this

```
var newDiv = "<li>"+names[i]+"<br><br><center><img src='"+images[i]+"'></img></center><br>"+subnames[i]+"</li>";
```

Comment: @King, did you mean format `.png`? It was asked  how to add it from array `images`, so I conclude that the `array` is already containing the format or full `url`, so there's no need to add the `.png` format

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var newDiv = "<li>"+names[i]+"<br><br><center><img src ="+names[i]+".png></img>    </center><br>"+subnames[i]+"</li>"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using this :

```
var newDiv= '<li>'+names[i]+'<br><br><center><img src = "'+images[i]+'"></img></center><br>'+subnames[i]+'</li>';
```